# Calling a constructor inside a constructor of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, default-constructor

This code has a templated class. The default constructor appears to call itself recursively. How can it do that? I don't understand this code. Maybe if I would be given an example without templates, just POD types, things would be clearer. I haven't encountered this construct before in C++ programming. I think that I don't understand both the constructor and the templates.

```
template <typename T>
class Simple {
  public:
    Simple(T value = T());    // What's this?
    T value();
    void set_value(T value);
  private:
    T value_;
};

template<typename T>
Simple<T>::Simple(T value) {
  value_ = value;
}

template<typename T>
T Simple<T>::value() {
  return value_;
}

template<typename T>
void Simple<T>::set_value(T value) {
  value_ = value;
}
```

My question is:
What does `T value = T()` do?

Comment: @George Can you write this in an actual answer? Provide an example of `Simple() = default;` in the class itself. It is not clear to me from the comment alone.

Comment: @George: it would not be equivalent for `Simple<int>` though. `0` vs uninitialized.

Comment: Is this recursion or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class Simple has a variable `value` of type `T` (Templated).

The constructor which you are pointing is a default constructor. When no parameter is supplied while creating `Simple` object. Then default constructor will instantiate the value object to the default constructor of T.

Either , `Simple(T value = T())` is a default constructor which is instantiating value to default constructor of typed element.

Example :- 
if T is String.

```
Simple (String value = String())
```

so value is now initialized to default of String().

Answer (score 0):

It is just a default value as `void foo(int i = 42);`, there are no recursion.

`foo();` is equivalent to `foo(42);`.

In the same way, with `Simple(T value = T());`

`Simple<int> s{};` would be equivalent to `Simple<int> s{0};` and
`Simple<std::string> s{};` would be equivalent to `Simple<std::string> s{std::string{}};` (empty string).

`T()` would call the default constructor of given `T` (`int` and `std::string` in my examples).

Comment: Can you clarify the last sentence? Why would these two expressions be equivalent? What would be the result if a different data type would be used?